# Deactivate automatic session lock in kde4

Tags: session, kde-4

I've looked around in the system settings on Kubuntu 9.10, but I really can't find a way to deactivate the automatic session lock in kde4. Anyone has found it?

I don't have a reason to lock the screen at home, and it's really bothering when watching a movie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under **System Settings -> Advanced -> Power Management** you can disable session locking.

Comment: You mean in general settings? This is one of the first places I've looked and I've already unchecked all the boxes there (both "Lock screen on resume" and "Let PowerDevil manage screen powersaving" are unchecked, and I guessed it would be enough). I've also edited the profiles and unchecked the "Dim display when idle for more than..." boxes in all of them, just in case. It doesn't do. 

Am I missing something?

Comment: Oh my, I just hadn't seen the line that says "When the system is idle for more than... " => Do nothing. In all profiles. Thanks for pointing me to this place... again ;-)